# How to display continously the image position while it is moving?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to display the image position while it is animating.
the Animation code is shown here,

```
[UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIImageView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
[UIImageView setAnimationRepeatCount:20];
CGPoint poss;
poss.x=150;
poss.y=328;
img2.center=poss;
[UIImageView commitAnimations];
```

Can any one tell me how to display the image position every microsecond in NSLog.

Answer (score 1):

Put timer function that calls a method having the below line and declare the img2 at class level at every microsecond or while you want to display

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(2/1000000) target:self selector:@selector(Log) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)Log {
    NSLog(@"X:%f \n Y:%f",img2.center.x,img2.center.y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the animation delegate object [setAnimationDelegate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#jumpTo_38) for receiving the start- and stop-message from your animation. In that functions you should set a BOOL that you can determine if the animation is still active.

To get the position write a function that would called with the help from an NSTimer, that log the position of your image if the animation is active, otherwise disable the timer.

Hope that helps...?